# Aggregate function not giving sum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query:

```
SELECT o.idorder,
    sum(CASE 
            WHEN cast(isnull(ama.FreeShiping, 0) AS INT) = 0
                THEN - 1000
            ELSE cast(isnull(ama.FreeShiping, 0) AS INT)
            END) FreeShiping
FROM OrderDetail od,
    amazonsku ama,
    orders o,
    TempPrintRecords tmp
WHERE o.idOrder = od.idOrder
    AND o.idCustomer = ama.idCustomer
    AND od.SKU = ama.Sku
    --and od.idOrder=350184
    AND od.idOrder = tmp.idOrder
    AND ama.FreeShiping != 0
GROUP BY o.idorder
```

Result:

[image]

Here I have 0 and null in `ama.FreeShiping`

Basically this column is bit and only contains 0 and 1. So if 0 is found I make it -1000 to identify `idorder` having 0 or null as `Freeshipping`

But it's not giving proper sum, It should give result in -ve for each column.

Comment: If you remove the `SUM()` and the `GROUP BY` I suspect you will find multiple lines for `idorder` 350184, and 350185, both of which will have a `ama.FreeShipping` of `1`. You sum those multiple lines and end up with `2` here.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if ama.freeshipping !=0 means no zero's so the case statement is worthless as you'll never have a zero.

Answer (score 1):

This expression in the `where` clause:

```
AND ama.FreeShiping != 0
```

only chooses values that are "1".  Remove this if you want to see other values.

You should also learn to use proper `join` syntax.  If you used the `join` keyword, then most of the conditions would be in `on` clauses, and this `where` condition might have been easier to spot.